# FPDF with Wordpress: not getting some data

Tags: php, wordpress, pdf-generation

```
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);

require('tfpdf.php');
require_once('.../public_html/wp-load.php');

$nif_onion= get_user_meta(get_current_user_id(),"nif", true);
$stand= the_title();
$name= get_the_author_meta("display_name",get_current_user_id());
```

I'm writing a script that generates a pdf file through TFPDF (better Unicode) with connection to a Wordpress database.
I can print on the pdf the result of functions like
get_the_author_meta("display_name",get_current_user_id())
or
get_user_meta(get_current_user_id(),"test", true)

So, I can get the get_current_user_id() data. I can get user data.

But I can't get the post data.
I have nothing returned from get_the_ID() or get_the_title() or anything that has to deal with
the post itself.

Any clue?
The pdf is generated through a button on the page that I want to get data from. And the page is generated from a template. Dynamically.

I am connected to the database (using require_once(.../wp-load.php))

I can get $nif_onion and $name pdf printed, $stand is not being pdf printed. If I have it through a code snipped I have $stand printed on the screen.

Thank you!

Comment: Provide the hooks code that you might have used for the PDF generate action on button click.

Comment: Your problem has very little to do with generating PDF files, it's about getting data in a  Wordpress page. It is nice to know what you want to use that data for, but a better focus on the problem itself would be helpful. Especially in the title of your question.

Comment: Well, when I implement get_the_title() inside Wordpress, I have output, but I don't have when I try it inside TPDF pdf. The strange thing is that I have access to user data and not to post data inside the pdf. Weird. However I have access to post data when I insert a code snippet on the page...

Comment: Is it a WordPress page/post when u use PDF page? You could check if there is title you are searching for passing $post or id to `get_the_title( int|WP_Post $post )`. If there would be empty string, then your page/post doesn't exist. Maybe you could use `apply_filters( 'the_title', string $title, int $id )`, or maybe try global variable `$post` like: `global $post; $post->post_title;`

Comment: Yes, the variable produced is a string and it's length is 0. I am starting to think that FPDF can't read a value from the page in which is generated. Specially if it is a dynamic page.  It can read a user related data (because the user stays logged), but it can't read data from the page from where it is generated.